# Find the constant $C$ for two integration results of the same expression

Tags: integration, derivatives

Integrating the following expression:
$$ \frac{2 M x}{R^3 \left(3 \sqrt{1-\frac{2 M}{R}} \sqrt{1-\frac{2 M x^2}{R^3}}-1\right)+2 M x^2} \quad \quad  x \geq 0, \quad  R>0, \quad M >0  \tag 1$$

with respect to $x$ using Mathematica yields
$$ -\frac{1}{2} \left(\log  \left(\frac{\sqrt{R^3-2 M x^2}}{3 R \sqrt{R-2 M}}+1\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log  \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{R^3-2 M x^2}}{3 R \sqrt{R-2 M}}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log  \left(-9 M R^2+M x^2+4 R^3\right) \tag 2 $$

but the result is also known to be from other sources as

$$ \log  \left(3 \sqrt{1-\frac{2 M}{R}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{2 M x^2}{R^3}}\right)   \tag 3$$
I don't see the resemblance between them. 
Both $(2)$ and $(3)$ have the same derivative with respect to $x$, but I cannot find the constant $C$ such that $(3) + C = (2)$. If I try to calculate $C$ I end up having $x$ in the expression which indicates it is not a constant.  I need to find $C$.

Comment: Just testing values, I'm pretty sure there's a typo as things are written. Try setting $x$ to $0$ or $1$ and setting them equal (with a $+C$), and assigning particular values of R,M. Methinks you get a problem.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but it does not seem to be the case. see   https://image.ibb.co/iKsCpk/schwarzschild.png